# How to break a time interval into smaller intervals by day

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I would like to break a time interval into smaller intervals, with a cut-off at 12:00 pm each day. Here is my example dataframe:

```
dftest <- data.frame(
  Subj = c("XX001", "XX001", "XX002", "XX002"),
  Start = c("2023-12-07 03:55:00", "2023-12-10 15:45:00", "2023-12-14 10:10:00", "2023-12-16 23:38:00"),
  End = c("2023-12-09 13:04:00", "2023-12-11 19:25:00", "2023-12-14 11:59:00", "2023-12-20 00:19:00")
)
```

```
> dftest
   Subj               Start                 End
1 XX001 2023-12-07 03:55:00 2023-12-09 13:04:00
2 XX001 2023-12-10 15:45:00 2023-12-11 19:25:00
3 XX002 2023-12-14 10:10:00 2023-12-14 11:59:00
4 XX002 2023-12-16 23:38:00 2023-12-20 00:19:00
```

And here is my expected output (using XX001 as an example):

```
> dftest_XX001
   Subj               Start                 End
1 XX001 2023-12-07 03:55:00 2023-12-07 12:00:00
2 XX001 2023-12-07 12:00:00 2023-12-08 12:00:00
3 XX001 2023-12-08 12:00:00 2023-12-09 13:04:00
...
...
...
```

I apologize if it has been asked before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for not putting my workings. I was thinking of extracting the dates between the start date and end date, then pasting 12:00:00 to each of these dates, but was stuck at as_date.


```
dftest <- dftest %>% 
  mutate(Start = ymd_hms(Start, tz = "Asia/Singapore"),
         End = ymd_hms(End, tz = "Asia/Singapore"))

dftest <- dftest %>%
  mutate(DateStart = date(Start),
         DateEnd = date(End))

dftest <- dftest %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(rr = list(as_date(seq(DateStart, DateEnd,by = "day")))) 

dftest <- dftest %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dd = list(as_date(rr)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `disag` function computes the boundary values, `bounds`, of intervals from the start datetime, noon on each intervening day and the end datetime.  Then it ensures that they are within the closed/closed interval between the start and end datetimes and that they are unique.  If there is only one bound left use that and otherwise remove the last and first for the start values and the end values.

```
library(dplyr)

disag <- function(st, en) {
  st1 <- as.POSIXct(st)
  en1 <- as.POSIXct(en)

  bounds <- 
    seq(from = trunc(st1, "day") - 12 * 60 * 60,
        to = trunc(en1, "day") + 12 * 60 * 60,
        by = 24 * 60 * 60) %>%
    c(st1, ., en1) %>%
    pmax(st1, .) %>%
    pmin(en1, .) %>%
    unique

  if (length(bounds) == 1) {
    Start <- End <- bounds 
  } else {
    Start <- head(bounds, -1)
    End <- tail(bounds, -1)
  }
  data.frame(Start, End) 
}


dftest %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  reframe(Subj = Subj, disag(Start, End))
```

Comment: Thank you @Grothendieck for the disag function! it's a brilliant solution, it didn't occur to me that I could use pmax, pmin to compare two vectors; and then use the head(., -1) and tail(., -1) to arrange the dataframe.